# Choropleth map not changing with slider. Using plotly and chart_studio

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

```
    Year    Country  Code   Total 
0   1751    United Kingdom  GBR 2552    
1   1752    United Kingdom  GBR 2553    
2   1753    United Kingdom  GBR 2553    
# data frame above

{'Year': {0: 1751, 1: 1752, 2: 1753, 3: 1754, 4: 1755},
 'Country': {0: 'United Kingdom',
 1: 'United Kingdom',
 2: 'United Kingdom',
 3: 'United Kingdom',
 4: 'United Kingdom'},
 'Country Code': {0: 'GBR', 1: 'GBR', 2: 'GBR', 3: 'GBR', 4: 'GBR'},
 'Total (thousand metric tons)': {0: 2552, 1: 2553, 2: 2553, 3: 2554, 
 4: 2555},
 'Solid Fuel': {0: 2552, 1: 2553, 2: 2553, 3: 2554, 4: 2555},
 'Liquid Fuel': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Gas Fuel': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Cement': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Gas Flaring': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Per Capita': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Bunker fuels (Not in Total)': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}}

# that is the full dataframe heading. Earlier, I only included the total 
column on here to make it more concise.


data = dict(
    type = 'choropleth',
    locations = df_countries['Country Code'],
    z = (df_countries['Total (thousand metric tons)']),
    colorscale="Portland",
    text = df_countries['Country'],
    colorbar = {'title' : 'Title'}
  ) 
# slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(years)): 
    step = dict(method='restyle',
            args=['visible', [False] * len(years)],
            label='Year {}'.format(i + 1751))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    i +=50
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(active=0,
            pad={"t": 1},
            steps=steps)]
```

So I'm having trouble displaying the data when I move the slider. And I cannot change the value of the slider despite i+=50. I'm still new to Python so please take it easy on me in the comments haha. Thanks so much for any help. I'll attach a picture as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include a larger portion of the sample data set in your question? If you include the output from the following: `df.head().to_dict()` – this will help make your problem a bit more reproducible – thanks!

Comment: I just added it, thanks for getting back so quickly. I'm only looking at plotting the 'Total (thousand metric tons)' column values on my choropleth. But maybe it's plotting a different column?

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at your code - instead of posting a screenshot, can you post the text from that output into the question? I want to be able to copy and paste your sample data so I can work with it myself. For now, I'll check your code for any obvious mistakes

Comment: Oh my bad, just updated.

Comment: Got everything working now, but thanks so much for trying.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer! I'll do so anyway since it might still be helpful for someone else with the same question as you - glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem was the way you are setting up the variable `data` is that it shouldn't be a lone dictionary - it needs to be a list of dictionaries where each dictionary corresponds to a separate trace. What the slider does is set which of these traces to display.

What is happening is that Plotly is interpreting your data to mean that you only have one trace, which is why the slider (which modifies whether multiple traces show up) isn't doing anything.

In your case, you want each position on the slider to correspond to a separate year, so each item in the `data` list should also correspond to a separate year. This can be done by dynamically creating data using a groupby on the "Year".

Another consideration is that you might want to control the zmin and zmax so the colorscale doesn't change for each trace.

I also added another country in the sample data to show that this method is generalizable.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio

## create some data similar to yours with multiple countries
## large enough changes so that the map picks up the color change

## each slider position corresponds to one of the years
df_countries = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [1751,1752,1753,1754,1755]*2,
    'Country': ['United Kingdom']*5 + ['Spain']*5,
    'Country Code': ['GBR']*5 + ['ESP']*5,
    'Total (thousand metric tons)': [2552, 3553, 4553, 5554, 6555] + [6552, 5553, 4553, 3554, 2555]
})

data = []

## we want each year's data to have a separate entry in the data list
for _,df_countries_group in df_countries.groupby('Year'):
    data.append(dict(
        type = 'choropleth',
        locations = df_countries_group['Country Code'],
        z = (df_countries_group['Total (thousand metric tons)']),
        zmin = 0,
        zmax = 7000,
        colorscale="Portland",
        text = df_countries_group['Country'],
        colorbar = {'title' : 'Title'}
    ))

# slider
steps = []
years = [1751,1752,1753,1754,1755]
for i in range(len(years)): 
    step = dict(method='restyle',
            args=['visible', [False] * len(years)],
            label='Year {}'.format(i + 1751))
    step['args'][1][i] = True

    ## with a smaller example, let's iterate through each year
    # i +=1
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(active=4,
            pad={"t": 1},
            steps=steps)]    

layout = dict(sliders=sliders)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
pio.show(fig)
```

[image]